# Ubuntu 15.10, if I suspend from toolbar it's ok, if I close laptop lid when I resume it keeps logging me out

Tags: suspend, laptop, power-management

So as the title states:

Ubuntu 15.10, if I suspend from toolbar it's ok, if I close laptop lid when I resume it keeps logging me out / going to lock screen after 10-20 seconds.

I have a razer laptop, I've tried some other suggestions (upstart vs systemd), graphics drivers etc but nothing has worked.

Comment: Can you please provide more detailed hardware informations?

Comment: Sure, sorry first question here what should I do there? It's the The New Razer Blade - QHD+ (512GB)

Comment: I enabled hibernate when shutdown, it still shows the same behaviour even after the hibernate restart

Comment: Like video card, net cards, and such... Obviously we need manufacturer and model of all the components.

Comment: NVIDIA Corporation GM204M [GeForce GTX 970M] (rev a1)

Comment: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)

Comment: What driver are you using for the video card?

Comment: I started with Nouveau display driver, then switched to NVIDA GM204M nvidia-352 tested, then nvidea-352-updates, all had the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to mint linux and was all good, it's ubuntu under the hood and better UI